# How do you send a invite to the server its in. (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Im trying to get a invite command but i cant figure out how to send a invite for the server the command was said in.

example:

User: $invite

Bot: Heres your invite link (invite link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create an invite you need to use [`await create_invite`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?#discord.abc.GuildChannel.create_invite). Here is an example of how to use this below.

```py
@client.command()
async def invite(ctx):
    link = await ctx.channel.create_invite(max_age = 300, max_uses=1) # all of these default to 0, aka forever
    await ctx.send(f"Invite for {ctx.author.mention}: {link}")
```

[image: Working code]

Also, next time you ask a question, please include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of some code that you have already tried, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

```
@client.command()
async def invite(ctx):
    invite = "Put invite link here"
    ctx.send(f"Here's your invite link: {invite}")
```

Just create a permanent invite link with infinite uses, and store it in a variable